# Demonstration that pure point set is countable if the measure is finite for every compact

Tags: measure-theory

I read on Reed and Simons' this statement.

Let P be the pure point set of a positive Borel measure $\mu$ on $\mathbb{R}$, that is $P = \{ x\, |\, \mu(\{x\}) > 0 \}$. Then this set is countable if $\;\mu(C)<+\infty $ for every C compact set.

Can anyone write a proof of this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Observe that $\forall K\text{ compact }\#(K\cap S)\leq\aleph_0$.

In fact, $\mu(K)<+\infty$, therefore let $S^K_n:=\left\{ x\in K\cap S :\mu(\{x\})\geq\frac{1}{n}\right\}$. It is obvious that $S_n^K$ contains at most $n\cdot\mu(K)$ points. Therefore $K\cap S=\bigcup_{n\in \mathbb{N^+}}S_n^K$ is at most countable.

Now $\#S\leq\aleph_0$ follows from the fact that $S=\bigcup_{m\in\mathbb{N}}S\cap[-m,m]$